# Is it possible to make a class package-private for testing purposes

Tags: java, testing

I have a class which is going to perform some complex action involving some computation like this:

```
public class ComplexAction {

    public void someAction(String parameter){
        ComplexActionEvaluator evaluator = new ComplexActionEvaluator();
        int value = evaluator.eval(parameter);
        //some other actions
    }

    static class ComplexActionEvaluator implements Evaluator{
        public int eval(String parameter){
            //evaluation
        }
    }
}

//package-private, uses only for Actions
interface Evaluator{
    int eval(String parameter);
}
```

Since the evaluator might contain some complex logic I'd like to write tests for it. But since the `ComplexActionEvaluator` is specific to the `ComplexAction` I'd do it private rather then package-private. But this would make it unavailable for testing.

The soulution first came to my mind was just to make it default-access. But the default-access is just for getting available for testing.

I think that it's not quite good if the decision on which access modifier to use is biased by testing. Maybe I do something wrong or it's a common practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple answer too that; as you are fully correct: the thing that would make sense (to only allow access for testing purposes) doesn't work in Java. I think other, newer languages actually introduced concepts that allow you to mark methods/classes to be "private only, but accessible for testing code"; but Java isn't there yet.

In that sense, you can only solve this by "conventions"; like:

1. Adding java-doc (or non-javadoc comments) to mark things that are "not private" for testing purposes
2. Ensure that things within your package that others should be using **always** carry **public** on team

In other words: as you only can "ask" people to ignore certain parts, you simply make sure that "really public" things are marked as such, and always documented as such; and everybody in your team understands: anything else is not of interest; and should be seen as "private implementation" detail.

Comment: Actually, the thing "if you cannot solve it in Java, do it in JavaDocs" kind of work, but it seems to me like a workaround. But I think that it this case, putting the `ComplexActionEvaluator` inside the `ComplexAction` is self-documented...

Comment: Actually, I think it is both: on the one hand, it is a workaround - to work around something that doesn't have a better solution. On the other hand: having proper javadoc is in itself a good thing; in that sense: one can use what is already there.